# Wordpress: wp_users & wp_userdata - when I add WHERE clause to SQL, some column data disappears

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

When I add the following WHERE clause to my sql, my first_name and last_name output is null. When I leave out the WHERE clause, first_name and last_name are populated.

```
    SELECT t1.id,
       t1.user_email,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t2.meta_key = 'first_name' THEN t2.meta_value
           END) AS first_name,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t2.meta_key = 'last_name' THEN t2.meta_value
           END) AS last_name
FROM   wp_users AS t1
       INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS t2
               ON t1.id = t2.user_id
WHERE  t2.meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%'
GROUP  BY t1.id,
          t1.user_email
```

Adding this WHERE clause, removes first_name and last_name:

**ID Email first_name last_name**
1  x@x.com

If I remove the WHERE clause I get first_name, last_name but I only want to display subscribers:

**ID Email   first_name last_name**
1  x@x.com John       Doe

Comment: Show us some sample data, the current result, and the wanted result - all as formatted text (no images.) Simplify! [mcve]

Comment: thanks -I've added formatted examples

Comment: A WHERE clause reduces the number of rows returned. It has nothing to do with the number of columns _you chose_ to SELECT. However, it seems like your WHERE removes the rows containing the first_name and last_name, i.e. the values the SELECT list case expressions are looking for.

Comment: Skip the GROUP BY, and the MAX() functions for a while, and you'll understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance -much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

***This worked for me:***

```
SELECT
   id,
display_name AS Company,
   user_email AS Email,
   user_login AS Login,
   
   (
      SELECT
         meta_value 
      FROM
         wp_usermeta 
      WHERE
         wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.id 
         AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name'
   )
   AS first_name,
   (
      SELECT
         meta_value 
      FROM
         wp_usermeta 
      WHERE
         user_id = wp_users.id 
         AND meta_key = 'last_name'
   )
   AS last_name,
   user_registered 
FROM
   wp_users 
   JOIN
      wp_usermeta 
      ON wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.id 
WHERE
   meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%' 
ORDER BY
   `display_name` ASC
```